# ionic build android –-release Error

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

When i run `ionic build android –-release` ,but it has no error, when I squeeze in the ionic serve, is there any way I can put trycatch in the ionic typescript?
[Picture here check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vshbp.png)

Comment: You have to give command **ionic cordova build android --prod --release** for taking release build

Comment: still giving the same error

Comment: Do you need production or development build

Comment: as well?I did not understand

Comment: if i use trycatch ?? how i can use trycatch ??